# Symbol and Packages not found

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a Github repository, https://github.com/GrammarViz2/grammarviz2_src. However, when I run the application on CMD, I get the error-

```
    GrammarVizGUI.java:4: error: package net.seninp.grammarviz.controller does not exist
import net.seninp.grammarviz.controller.GrammarVizController;
                                       ^
GrammarVizGUI.java:5: error: package net.seninp.grammarviz.model does not exist
import net.seninp.grammarviz.model.GrammarVizModel;
                                  ^
GrammarVizGUI.java:6: error: package net.seninp.grammarviz.view does not exist
import net.seninp.grammarviz.view.GrammarVizView;
                                 ^
GrammarVizGUI.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
  private static GrammarVizModel model;
                 ^
  symbol:   class GrammarVizModel
  location: class GrammarVizGUI
GrammarVizGUI.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
  private static GrammarVizController controller;
                 ^
  symbol:   class GrammarVizController
  location: class GrammarVizGUI
GrammarVizGUI.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
  private static GrammarVizView view;
                 ^
  symbol:   class GrammarVizView
  location: class GrammarVizGUI
GrammarVizGUI.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    model = new GrammarVizModel();
                ^
  symbol:   class GrammarVizModel
  location: class GrammarVizGUI
GrammarVizGUI.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
    controller = new GrammarVizController(model);
                     ^
  symbol:   class GrammarVizController
  location: class GrammarVizGUI
GrammarVizGUI.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    view = new GrammarVizView(controller);
               ^
  symbol:   class GrammarVizView
  location: class GrammarVizGUI
9 errors
```

However, on closer examination I see that many of the packages are present within the source, inside multiple folders. I have almost zero experience with running Java code, hence I believe that I must be making some silly error.

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: I am using the Java Development Kit.

Comment: This project is meant to be compiled using Apache Maven (http://maven.apache.org). It is a dependency manager for Java. It requires the JDK to run

Comment: @CircuitCraft Got it! Thanks for the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things missing, let's do it step by step:

There is missing a jar-plugin configuration (assembly plugin configuration is not sufficient to provide `Main-Class` in `MANIFEST.MF`

Add this plugin configuration into `profile` `single`

```
...
<profile>
    <id>single</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>net.seninp.grammarviz.GrammarVizGUI</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <!-- <filters> <filter>src/assembly/filter.properties</filter> </filters> 
                        <descriptors> <descriptor>src/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor> </descriptors> -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>net.seninp.grammarviz.GrammarVizGUI</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <!-- <filters> <filter>src/assembly/filter.properties</filter> </filters> 
                        <descriptors> <descriptor>src/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor> </descriptors> -->
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
...
```

Then You need to use this profile during build:

```
mvn -Psingle clean package
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.949 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-21T21:30:25+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/435M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It creates 2 `jar` files in `target` directory:

```
grammarviz2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
grammarviz2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Then You need to run the application (from `target` directory):

```
java -jar grammarviz2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

This `jar` contains a `MANIFEST.MF` file (`/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`) which was configured above in `pom.xml` with proper entries to run this `jar` as an application without providing main class.

"Works on my machine":

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Linux Mint 18.3
```

Comment: Did you run the GrammarVizGUI?

Comment: Thanks zolv! I up voted your answer but since my reputation is low, it may not be seen :)

Comment: @Deepak-GeorgeThomas You can still pick my answer as acepted by You :)

Comment: I am unable to find MANIFEST.MF (as stated in your answer) anywhere. Could you please elaborate on the same?

Comment: I just figured it out!

Comment: NP, I added info to my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the jar file with dependencies. In Intellij it is like that:

> File -> Project Structure -> artifacts -> click on the '+' -> JAR ->
>   from modules with dependencies

Then a small window shows up, where you have to specify which class the main method has, then click ok and also ok in the project structure. Then build the artifacts and navigate into the artifacts folder, where the jar file will be created normally in the projects out folder named artifacts.

Comment: Thanks Sophia! I up voted your answer but since my reputation is low, it may not be seen :)